# Remove decoration when hovering links

Tags: html, css

I was wondering if there is any way for my links not to get underlined/change color when I hover them.

Comment: what do you mean "order"? you could mabe use `<span class="class" id="id"></span>`

Comment: You can definitely make a link look like regular text. Is this what you are asking?

Comment: you said text highlighted as alink - this is actually link. `<a>` tag is an anchor

Comment: "<a class="class" id="id"></a> it highlights the text like it is a link" <a> IT IS a link, if you don't want to highlighted then you need to use CSS to change the behavior of that particular link using a specific class for that/those links or change all links on your web page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well `<a>` tag is used for links. But if you want to have link in a text without the decorations in it i recommend you to use CSS. Add this to your `<head>` tag.

```
<style type="text/css">
     a.class{
       text-decoration:none;
       color:#000000;//Your default color
     }
</style>
```

Else try to clarify what you want to do.

Comment: Yes, that was what I was lolking for. Sorry to other people who knew it and couldn't understand what I wrote. You are free to devote me x).

Comment: don't forget to vote the answer and mark it as an answer.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure exactly what your issue is, but you can definitely find ways around highlighted text if that's the critical issue here. What I might try, is wrap this code in a `<div>` tag and give the class to the `<div>`. It may looks something like this:

```
<div class="yourClass" id="yourID">
<a href="http://wwww.YOURLINK.com">Highlighted Link Text</a>
</div>
```

And use CSS to deal with the `text-decoration`.
You should only use the `<a>` tag if you're looking to link. Otherwise, use something like the `<p>` (paragraph) tag.